# Is it possible to use ProxyPass with only one ip address

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, ajp

I am looking to achieve this configuration. So I tried this but the server is allways looking for `server_test` and `server_prod` in the `htdocs` under Apache. What I want is to redirect the request to the Tomcat server. If I use different ports without the /server_test and /server_prod, it worked but it's not what I wanted.

```
<virtualhost mydomaine.com/server_test:80>
    ServerName mydomaine.com    
    ProxyRequests Off  
    ProxyPass / ajp://internalIp:8008/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomaine.com/server_test/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost mydomaine.com/server_prod:80>
    ServerName mydomaine.com    
    ProxyRequests Off     
    ProxyPass / ajp://internalIp:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomaine.com/server_prod/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</virtualhost>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<virtualhost mydomaine.com:80>
   ServerName mydomaine.com    
   ProxyRequests Off  
   ProxyPass /server_test ajp://internalIp:8008/
   ProxyPass /server_prod ajp://internalIp:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse /server_test ajp://internalIp:8008/
   ProxyPassReverse /server_prod ajp://internalIp:8009/
</virtualhost>
```

However, you would not be able to use `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`, because both Tomcat sites would set cookies with `/` as the path.

To make it work as I believe you want, you need to have two separate `VirtualHost`s. If you only have one IP address, you need to use name-based virtual hosts.

For example, add a subdomain `test.mydomaine.com` that has the same IP address as `mydomaine.com`. Then use this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost mydomaine.com:80
<virtualhost mydomaine.com:80>
  ServerName mydomaine.com    
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / ajp://internalIp:8009/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://internalIp:8009/
</virtualhost>
<virtualhost mydomaine.com:80>
  ServerName test.mydomaine.com    
  ProxyRequests Off  
  ProxyPass / ajp://internalIp:8008/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://internalIp:8008/
</virtualhost>
```

You can then access your production site at http://mydomaine.com/ and your test site at http://test.mydomaine.com/.

Comment: In the end I used two different subdomains with two NameVirtualHost and virtualhost for each subdomain.